# Получить список методов и параметров Web-сервиса

Tags: c#, asp.net

Столкнулся с задачей: после подключения к веб-сервису нужно **получить список его методов** и **параметров** к ним (если есть). Голову сейчас ломаю - подключился я, а что делать дальше, ума не приложу. Есть идеи, как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Leonard Bertone кроме простого перебора - никак. Веб-приложение *может* предоставлять свою схему, но вряд ли будет.

Comment: Я ОШИБСЯ: не Web-сервера а Web-сервИСа. Простите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@Leonard Bertone](/users/22720/leonard-bertone)](/users/22720/leonard-bertone), тогда, возможно, у веб-сервиса есть WSDL-описатель. Обычно доступен по адресу вида http://myserver/somepath/MyService?wsdl , где

- `myserver` - это хост и порт сервера, на котором развернут веб-сервис
- `somepath` - путь к enpoint-у веб-сервиса
- `MyService` - endpoint веб-сервиса

Comment: WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:44764/wsTest.asmx/HelloWorld?wsdl");
я таким образом делаю, но если честно само описание в результате найти не могу. может я не совсем верно к  сервису обращаюсь?

Comment: Не знаю, как это принято делать в C#, но обычно из WSDL можно сгенерировать класс-обертку, в котором и будут все доступные методы.

---

Если хотите просто в отладочных целях подергать методы веб-сервиса - есть удобная бесплатная тула - SoapUI.

Comment: а Вы не знаете, как прочитать wsdl файлик и стянуть оттуда все методы и их параметры веб.сервиса?

Comment: Обычным браузером можно прочитать. [WSDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) - это не более чем XML с определенной структурой. Некоторые люди даже вполне способны писать его руками )

Comment: это понятно. имею в виду, как это сделать с помощью C#/ASP ?

Comment: да и правильно ли так делать вообще? Я просто никакого выхода другого не вижу, только так получить список методов веб-сервиса.

Answer (score 1):

Как вам уже сказали, [WSDL](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=949.UaSrmlS_KxHm7KgH9GaLwMxOSqPCOxG8LYAAwSverfk.5edecc153652c87de2387c960f283bed91d5e31d&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9T6U0-imFY5Ibl_FxS8ahbetb9q-Ws8tqQaT6YcO5ES2WU_XNsggvSsFTfHqJ8Yy-1diqrUkiHwNVkMEv806VSQ&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejY4cHFySjRXSWhXQzdLY3hSTVNzV2ZCVXgzZzFIWmJXemRtSl9GU3pqWkpjZXFoVmZjSGhCWjZwLWJ0WDRZclk5WTVYRFdZNEQtVkQ2R1hyNkV4b0Yyd0xwUU54TjVqZGk1ZUlZbWhzNFB3dw&b64e=2&sign=891608c7947b7b97946fb3f88452111e&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ4CiF6OxvZkNHHAYOBoviJrkE7HMwuKKIvkNc-GFNCBjiHXMqz1XllVAUZwZgck5lWDI-mvBqBai_8kVofGcWxheNaTc3HCc44_cdCl4J2yd_m1i5Vfp5gsmR3Dv839i2ow6oqEiFEfO64i8m6YXmTA9bpB7y42TvhOGS9mzoB2Vsf8Q0r87ikeyT_WCjjVb5ZCpCwUe1hOQt2VoeLaD5DGZSlGaPZcxeeugNYSCRVE3TAShKmZQVpo1dX4cvxqryYUpwBIgl1594maHBYMi4PLFP5awNhGwVE7w44iqjIMZfb_J7aK1uFu3tQO32jjdS_6vUmnbizF8aM7T6Vl8djqwRZFzOvO2oXK8M9qs8MYZC036JWIVAqCMYhsVMhEYoWyppkJl3GQanjzkYPTB1_iEUuyysGtyjs&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpj8xvXDTMTDnbC3EqI0CryOSFJej-TVPl&l10n=ru&cts=1454173280211&mc=0) - это язык описания веб-сервиса, который описывает контракт сервиса - список методов и параметров, которые сервис реализует.
В одном из проектов получал wsdl сервиса. Вот мои функции для получения wsdl web-сервиса.

```
private static MetadataSet GetMetadataSet(string url)
{
            MetadataExchangeClientMode mode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.MetadataExchange;
            int maxReceivedMessageSize = 3000000;
            Uri address = new Uri(url);

            Binding mexBinding = null;
            if (string.Compare(address.Scheme, "http", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding();
            else if (string.Compare(address.Scheme, "https", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpsBinding();
            else if (string.Compare(address.Scheme, "net.tcp", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexTcpBinding();
            else if (string.Compare(address.Scheme, "net.pipe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                mexBinding = MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexNamedPipeBinding();
            else
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Not supported schema '{0}' for metadata exchange"));

            if (mexBinding is WSHttpBinding)
            {
                (mexBinding as WSHttpBinding).MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxReceivedMessageSize;
                mode = MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet;
            }
            else if (mexBinding is CustomBinding)
                (mexBinding as CustomBinding).Elements.Find<TransportBindingElement>().MaxReceivedMessageSize = maxReceivedMessageSize;
            else
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Not supported binding for metadata exchange"));

            MetadataExchangeClient proxy = new MetadataExchangeClient(mexBinding);
            proxy.ResolveMetadataReferences = true;
            MetadataSet mds = proxy.GetMetadata(address, mode);
            return mds;
}
```

Функция возвращает объект класса [Metadataset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.servicemodel.description.metadataset(v=vs.100).aspx). Этот класс содержит метаданные службы.

Чтобы получить текст wsdl из этого объекта используя такую функцию

```
private void SaveWsdlToFile(MetadataSet metadata, string fileName)
{
            // Check for the metadata set size. 
            Collection<MetadataSection> documentCollection = metadata.MetadataSections;
            if (documentCollection != null && documentCollection.Count > 0)
            {
                //Get the WSDL from the metadata set
                System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription wsdl = (System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription)documentCollection[0].Metadata;

                //Save the WSDL to a file.
                wsdl.Write("BapiTx.wsdl");  

            }
}
```

Здесь мы получили объект [System.Web.Services.Description.ServiceDescription](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.description.servicedescription(v=vs.110).aspx) - объект для работы с wsdl файлом. Имея wsdl файл, можно вытащить список его методов и параметров, которые принимает сервис.